# How to get a simple list from a list comprehension that returns a list of lists

Tags: python

The code below:

```
spices={
'Animals':{1:'Bison', 2:'Panther', 3:'Elephant'},      
'Birds':{1:'Duck', 2:'Hawk', 3:'Pigeon'}, 
'Fish':{1:'Shark', 2:'Salmon', 3:'Piranha'}
}

result=[spices[specie].values() for specie in spices]
print result
```

results to a list of list:

```
[['Shark', 'Salmon', 'Piranha'], ['Bison', 'Panther', 'Elephant'], ['Duck', 'Hawk', 'Pigeon']]
```

But my goal is to get a simple list such as:

```
['Shark', 'Salmon', 'Piranha', 'Bison', 'Panther', 'Elephant', 'Duck', 'Hawk', 'Pigeon']
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a loop in the list comprehension; nested loops run from left to right:

```
[v for specie in spices for v in spices[specie].values()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> spices={
... 'Animals':{1:'Bison', 2:'Panther', 3:'Elephant'},      
... 'Birds':{1:'Duck', 2:'Hawk', 3:'Pigeon'}, 
... 'Fish':{1:'Shark', 2:'Salmon', 3:'Piranha'}
... }
>>> [v for specie in spices for v in spices[specie].values()]
['Shark', 'Salmon', 'Piranha', 'Bison', 'Panther', 'Elephant', 'Duck', 'Hawk', 'Pigeon']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention another approach:

```py
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x: x.values(), spices.values()))
```

Output:

```
['Shark', 'Salmon', 'Piranha', 'Bison', 'Panther', 'Elephant', 'Duck', 'Hawk', 'Pigeon']
```

Explanation (from right to left):

- Take all `values` of the outer dictionary.
- Extract the `values` of each nested dictionary via `map` and a custom `lambda` function.
- Concatenate all values via `reduce` and another custom `lambda` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain
spices={
'Animals':{1:'Bison', 2:'Panther', 3:'Elephant'},
'Birds':{1:'Duck', 2:'Hawk', 3:'Pigeon'},
'Fish':{1:'Shark', 2:'Salmon', 3:'Piranha'}
}

print list(chain.from_iterable(spices[specie].values() for specie in spices))
['Shark', 'Salmon', 'Piranha', 'Bison', 'Panther', 'Elephant', 'Duck', 'Hawk', 'Pigeon']
```